# Passing Data Between Different Navigation Pages in WPF C# application and Representation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm very unclear about how does the control shifts between two pages when navigating in a WPF application.
What I'm trying to achieve is I have a database with some tables, in one of the tables I have Names and I represent these names in a ListBox on the first page.
Now when a user clicks one Name and presses button below the `ListBox` this navigates the user to the Detailed information about the Clicked User( Choosen From the List )

Now the problem is the tutorial I'm following is [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752299(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_10) and the problem starts with the Binding Data To A Control.

1. the tutorial follows a static `<xaml>` as the datasource and I have a data in a Database.
2. After I click on the one User [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752299(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_11) is how I'm supposed to show the next page, but in my case the selected item is not a `<Person></Person>` block of data but it will be obtained by querying the DATABASE itself.
3. So I cannot find a resource that addresses this issue for the beginners.
4. As I can see the data is extracted on the `ExpanseItHome.xaml.cs`

:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // View Expense Report
    ExpenseReportPage expenseReportPage = new ExpenseReportPage(this.peopleListBox.SelectedItem);
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(expenseReportPage);
}
```

page and than passed as context to the constructor

```
public ExpenseReportPage(object data):this()
{
    // Bind to expense report data.
    this.DataContext = data;
}
```

of the `ExpanseItReportPage.xaml.cs` but how will I implement this when interacting with database and the list for `names( ListBox )` items are also fetched from the database not from the xml source.

5. I'm from web-developing background, can I just pass the value of the selected item to the ExpanseItReportPage and than perform the query on the same page and Present the reports about the selected user or I have to go with the way that is described in the tutorial that is all the work is done it the `ExpanseItHome.xaml.cs` page (page with names ) and than data is passed to the Report page for Presentation.
6. **To be very plain I mean I need a tutorial or demo to help me with understanding how to create a multipage WPF application with database. (Ex. A Contact Book application Where main page is a list of NAMES and on clicking these names it takes us to a new page containing Address and Other Contact Related Info )**

Please do feel free to provide any resources that addresses creating Database based WPF application in C# that includes navigating between different pages while querying the database for the scenarios as the one described above.

Thanks

Comment: Consider this, fetch your data from db and put on a collection eg. `Collection<Person>`, this will also be your data context for the first page. The on selecting a `Person' from the list pass that person to you second window. The `Person` object you passed will be the data context for your details view.

Comment: You have populated the listbox with data from the database, and the problem is to pass it onto ExpenseReportPage?

Comment: yes, and Present the data according to the Layout of the ExpanseReportPage and the data is related to the chosen item from listbox and not the same as the data in the listbox